# Automatically send object to every res.render()

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I have a config object that I want to use in pretty much every view on my express appplication. It looks something like this:

```
{
  "url" : "http://whatever.com",
  "more" : "yadda yadda"
}
```

I want to have is accessible to all my views so I can easily reference `config.url`

Problem is that I don't want to pass this variable every time I do a `res.render('viewname')`

With express, is it possible to just always have this available? Am I even doing this right or does express have something for this already?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the properties are static (the same for all requests), use app.locals.

```
app.locals = {
  "url" : "http://whatever.com",
  "more" : "yadda yadda"
};
```

Variables set with `app.set()` are automatically accessible through settings.x in a view.
See [the docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.locals).